# How can I have smaller font than \tiny?

Tags: fontsize, tikz-styles

I'm using tikz for drawing, and the label are to big, I'm using the `font=\tiny` parameter, but it's still to big.
How can I reduce more the font size?

```
\draw [<->,line width=0.02cm] ($(first_joint.center) + (0.75, 0)$) node (yaxis) [above, font=\tiny] {$y_{_1}$}
                -| ($(first_joint.center) + (0, -0.75)$) node (xaxis) [left, font=\tiny] {$x_{_1}$};
```

Comment: You can use the option `scale`.

Comment: I just want to change only size of the labels.

Comment: The scale is working fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\fontsize` (and `\selectfont`) with a good font like `lmodern`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1pt]
   \node[font=\tiny]{A};
   \node[text=red,font=\fontsize{3}{3.5}\selectfont]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```